# Creating a setup file

Tags: python, installation, installshield

I will start by saying that I have never created an app that required installation and I have no idea how it works. But now I have to, and I am wondering how to proceed, use some kind os installation tools (installshield, wix) or create a python script and turn into an .exe.

What my install needs to do is:

- create a folder and add it to the system path
- check a repo via http for the latest version of a file and download it into that folder

How can I approach this?
Also, if I use any installation tools, can that setup file be used for updating?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The usual way to distribute and install Python packages is described here:

https://hynek.me/articles/sharing-your-labor-of-love-pypi-quick-and-dirty/

But I am not certain that is what you are looking for.
If I take your question literally:

- create a folder and add it to the system path
- check a repo via http for the latest version of a file and download it into that folder

I would go for a Python script, since it is not too complicated and you are in full control then.

Answer (score 1):

The recommended way to build a Windows setup is by using the Windows Installer technology. You can try to create your setup using a paid installer tool like InstallShield, Advanced Installer or any Windows Installer based tool or by using the free [WiX](http://wix.tramontana.co.hu/).

Regarding your second question, I'm not aware if WiX provides any built-in updating tools, but most of the paid installer tool have such built-in tools for handling and deploying installation updates.