# How to make a setup file which will install Python and dependencies on one's computer

Tags: python, tkinter, exe

I have been trying to package my Tkinter app. I tried Cx-freeze and Pyinstaller. I am having some troubles with correctly creating text files, writing into and reading from them. The app works fine when not converted into an exe but does not when converted. I am using absolute paths.
All this led me into asking this question:
**Is there any way to create a setup file that, when run, will install Python (downloaded already) and .whl files of the dependencies? This way, the app will work on others computer in its original form.**

My program is dependent on Tkinter, os, time, PyMuPDF, re, pandas and numpy.

Initially, I tried to work out a solution but could resolve [Errorno2] from pyinstaller. I searched the internet but could not find a satisfactory solution.  I am really hoping to have a setup file instead.
I read [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70986994/how-can-i-make-installer-which-install-python) and [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26928817/creating-a-setup-file).

Comment: Hi, welcome to StackOverflow. Please take the [tour](https://stackoverflow.com/tour) and learn [How to Ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask).
Share what you have done so far and provide a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).

Comment: Using absolute path in the application may not work in other computer even without using pyinstaller.

Comment: My app lets users browse a pdf.  I retrieve the root folder with `os` and then save pdf's text into a txt file in the root folder. Pyinstaller return [Error no2]